# How does Google choose "Desktop" or "Smartphone" for the "primary crawler" of a site?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers

How is the "primary crawler" selected for a site in Google Search Console (coverage segment)?

This picture belongs to 2 different websites:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is slowly moving all sites to mobile first indexing. i.e. Smartphone crawler.

I believe the decision to switch a site to mobile first is based on their analysis of the mobile v desktop versions. If they look similar the switch will probably be quick. If it looks like the site will lose out due to the switch, they may wait more time.

Comment: Adding to what Tony said - this is the process for existing websites; for new websites, they already moved to mobile-first indexing as default.